# C++ object lifetime profiling

Tags: c++, design-patterns, rtti

ObjectInfo class is a diagnostic class intended to track statistical data such as life time and number of objects. A specific class inherits from ObjectInfo as shown.  A member of that specific class is then declared in the body of a profiled class.

Although the solution works it is hard to maintain as it requires the profiling class to be keep in sync with the profiled class as the class name is used to identify the later. It would also be hard to extend the profiling class to gather different information such as the size of object.

Propose a better solution where the dependencies between the profiled and profiling classes are minimal.

Is it possible to implement a check that would determine if the object of the profiled class was created on stack or heap?

-- ObjectInfo.h --

```
#pragma once

class ObjectInfo
{
 public:
  ObjectInfo(const char* objectName);
  virtual ~ObjectInfo(void);

 private:

   static int  m_counter;
   int         m_objectNumber;
   const char* m_className;
};
```

-- ObjectInfo.cpp --

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "ObjectInfo.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "TimePrinter.h"

using namespace std;
int ObjectInfo::m_counter = 0;
ObjectInfo::ObjectInfo(const char* name) :
m_className(name)
{
   m_objectNumber = ++m_counter;
   cout << "Object: " << m_className << "# " << m_objectNumber << " created @ " <<
   TimePrinter()<< endl;
}

ObjectInfo::~ObjectInfo(void)
{
  cout << "Object: " << m_className << "# " << m_objectNumber << " destroyed @ " << 
  TimePrinter() << endl;
}
```

-- The use pattern --

```
struct _AInfo : public ObjectInfo {
    _AInfo() : ObjectInfo("_A") {}
};

struct _A {
  _AInfo m_info;
};
```

I originally thought this question is asking about using C++ reflection technique to gather the runtime information. However, I don't know if there is a way to measure the lifetime of objects using C++ reflection. Furhter, can you consider C++ reflection is a technique that reduces the dependencies between the profiled and profiling classes ?

Comment: I think you could make `ObjectInfo` a template and inherit from it directly : `class A : public ObjectInfo<A>`.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: that's called CRTP, the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern.

Comment: I *knew* I've stumbled on this before :P

Comment: Curiously Recurring Template Pattern! This is very Curious! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can track stack vs. heap object creations

```
#include <iostream>

template <class CRTP>
struct AllocationTracker
{
    AllocationTracker()
    {
        ++totalCreated;
    }

    void* operator new(size_t sz)
    {
        ++heapCreated;
        return ::operator new(sz);
    }

    static int totalCreated;
    static int heapCreated;
};

template <class CRTP>
int AllocationTracker<CRTP>::totalCreated;
template <class CRTP>
int AllocationTracker<CRTP>::heapCreated;

class Derived : public AllocationTracker<Derived>
{
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << Derived::heapCreated << "/" << Derived::totalCreated << endl; // 0/0
    Derived dStack;
    cout << Derived::heapCreated << "/" << Derived::totalCreated << endl; // 0/1
    Derived* dHeap = new Derived;
    cout << Derived::heapCreated << "/" << Derived::totalCreated << endl; // 1/2
}
```

This uses the CRTP that Bartek brought up in the comments on your question.  This lets us track each derived type separately.  It also wraps the standard `new` for the base class, which is inherited by derived classes, which allows us to track heap allocations.  So we know how many instances are created, and how many on the heap, and we can infer that the rest were on the stack (unless you're using object pools or some other more exotic allocation strategies in your program).

Comment: How do you deal with class name in this case? Do you still pass the class name as a string?

Comment: I don't have any book recommendations, though I'm sure Amazon.com does.  As for the class name, well, you can add your way of passing it as a string to my solution, or you can consider simply using `typeid(CRTP).name()` to get it automatically (albeit with a platform-specific format).

Comment: When I have a second thought about the question: "Is it possible to determine if the object was created on stack or heap?", I think the answer is very intriguing. Consider this question in a multithreading environment, two objects are created simultaneously. Only one is created on the heap, can you determine which one is on the heap?

Comment: Sure.  In the custom operator new, just record each address before returning it.  Use a std::set or something.  Then, when you want to know if a particular object is on the heap, just check if `this` is in the set of heap-allocated addresses.  I guess you should remove from the set on delete, too.

Comment: wow, Thank you very much. Sorry I didn't have enough reputation for voting. Your answer deserved to be appreciated.

Comment: I think you should be able to "accept" my answer by clicking the checkmark on its left side.