# C++: CRTP: How to know all objects count?

Tags: c++, crtp

I need you guys help in (may be basic question, sorry for that) in CRTP.
This is based on following posts:
[C++ object lifetime profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15050622/c-object-lifetime-profiling)
[How to count the number of CRTP subclasses of a template class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11113702/how-to-count-the-number-of-crtp-subclasses-of-a-template-class)

Using CRTP, we can able to count the number of objects created for each class type. But, using this approach I can't find the total number of objects created in the system.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
SNR

Comment: Please make the question self-contained.

Comment: Is you program single- or multi-threaded?

Comment: @Mateusz Grzejek, I want to do it for single threaded as of now. But future requirement may be for multi threaded. As you told, this is for maintaining object profile info and want to add object size and any other object related info.

Comment: For now (counting only) you would only have to change incrementation of counters to atomic op (via std::atomic [C++11], _InterlockedIncrement() [Windows] or some GCC intrinsics [Linux]). If content stored for each class grows, you will need to make sure that multiple threads can write to it without conflicts or locking (probably using std::mutex [C++11], CriticalSection [Windows] ot pthread's mutex [Linux]).

Comment: In case of multi threading, you should make the counter variables as from @MateuszGrzejek's answer [`std::atomic<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)'s

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, thank you. From your other post, "introduce some kind of class traits category access point for such case", can you please elaborate little more? it might be useful in my design of that feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution contains code for both (per-class and global) counters.

```
extern size_t Global_counter; //In .cpp file define it: size_t Global_counter = 0;

template <class T>
class CountedClass
{
protected:
  static size_t this_class_counter;

public:
  static size_t GetThisClassCounter()
  {
    return this_class_counter;
  }

  static size_t GetGlobalCounter()
  {
    return Global_counter;
  }

  CountedClass()
  {
    ++this_class_counter;
    ++Global_counter;
  }
};

template <class T>
size_t CountedClass<T>::this_class_counter = 0;
```

Sample usage:

```
class A : public CountedClass<A>
{
public:
  A() : CountedClass<A>()
  {
  }
};

class B : public CountedClass<B>
{
public:
  B() : CountedClass<B>()
  {
  }
};

A a1;
A a2;
B b2;

std::cout<<A::GetThisClassCounter(); //prints 2
std::cout<<A::GetGlobalCounter(); //prints 3

std::cout<<B::GetThisClassCounter(); //prints 1
std::cout<<B::GetGlobalCounter(); //prints 3
```

Comment: +1 Good solution! Would be even better if you factor out the getter for `GetGlobalCounter` from the classes (shouldn't be too hard).

Comment: Thanks. If one wants to remove GetGlobalCounter() from within the class, this can be done with no problem - just make it global function. I placed it there, however, for a reason - look at sample code, it looks more intuitive IMO. You treat global counter as a part of each class, not a standalone variable. But this is a matter of taste, I think :)

Comment: May be, it could be useful to introduce some kind of class traits category access point for such case.

Answer (score 0):

Have all classes inherit from a common base class which keeps a counter, something like

```
class Counter {
  static int count = 0;

protected:
  Counter() { count++; }

public:
  int getCount() { return count; }
};
```

As you want to count *all* the instances you don't need to distinguish different derived classes, so you don't need CRTP.

If you want both counts you can use a class like the one above as a base class for your CRTP class.

Comment: In provided example, each class already inherits from `Counted` class, so your solution introduces multiple inheritance, which is not necessary for such simple task. Since it's only profile info, non-intrusive method should be chosen.

Comment: I did not suggest that multiple inheritance be used, read better. Having a class like mine as a base class for a class template like the one in your example is not that more intrusive and better encapsulated than using a global variable. If you don't want to be intrusive use a memory analyzer, not base classes.

Comment: @Nicola Musatti, thank you very much for the code. I was looking for a  class which can say when derived class object is created and destroyed with its class name (really want to do with object name). So the qn comes for the object profiling from the first link. If I want to hold that information for an object, I felt CRTP is good. Bcz, with CRTP I can get the class name and can say when it is created, destroyed and size of that class.